# Multiple replace in one call

Tags: javascript, regex, function, replace

To remove the possible hash at the end of the string

```
.replace(/#.*$/,'')
```

is used.
To remove possible slash at the end of the string

```
.replace(/\/$/, '')
```

is used.

To remove possible hash and/or possible slash, both `.replace(/#.*$/,'').replace(/\/$/, '')` are used. Right?

Any possible shorthand for `.replace(/#.*$/,'').replace(/\/$/, '')`?

Thank you.

Comment: The first one doesn't replace the ``#`` at the end.

Comment: @Kokogino Both "abcd#ef".replace(/#.*$/,'') and "abcd#".replace(/#.*$/,'') gives us "abcd". So why do you think The first one doesn't replace the # at the end?  Thank you.

Comment: You don't need `$` for `#`: `.replace(/#.*|\/$/,'')`

Comment: @Haradzieniec Sorry, what I meant is that it doesn't just replace the ``#`` at the end but also the ``#`` in between. And it removes everything that's after the ``#``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take both in one regex:

```
.replace(/[#\/]*$/, '')
```

EDIT:

If you also want to remove the `#` in between:

```
.replace(/#|[#\/]*$/g, '')
```

EDIT:

If you also want to remove everything after the first `#`:

```
.replace(/#.*$|\/*$/, '')
```

Comment: Sorry, but "abcd#ef".replace(/[#\/]*$/, '')  doesn't remove #ef from the string.

Answer (score 1):

You have two regexps that follow a similar "scheme": `<SOME_SPECIFIC_PATTERN>` + `$`. In these cases, when there are sequences of patterns before `$`, it is easy to use a [*grouping* construct](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) with an [alternation operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
/(?:#.*|\/)$/
 ^^^   ^  ^
```

Where

```
/(?:<PATTERN_1>|<PATTERN_2>|<PATTERN_N>)$/
```

However, perhaps, to match a hashtag, you'd want to use either a `#\w+` (a `#` and 1+ word chars) or `#\S+` (a `#` and 1+ non-whitespace chars) pattern.